# What does a function name indicate and more

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Consider this  simple program:

```
#include <iostream>

void length(void){
    std::cout<<"My length is void"<<std::endl;
}

void width(void){
    std::cout<<"My width is void"<<std::endl;
}

int main(void){
    std::cout<<"The program length is: "<<length<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"The program width is: "<<width<<std::endl;
}
```

The output of this  program is:

```
The program length is: 1
The program width is: 1
```

What are the numbers that the program prints out, and basically not having much knowledge in C++ particularly, this  looks  more pythonic  syntax  to me,and looks  as if  it should  print the function address. I say this because, this problem arose initially while practicing some very basic programs for openGL,

The callback was registered  in GLUT with something like:

```
void line(void){
   //some code for line program ...
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    //some more code;
    glutDisplayFunc(line);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

It's almost seeming as if we're  passing the address of the function, but, clearly from the above  program this is not an address,  and the syntax for pointer to function is a bit different, if so, **how is this  function being  registered for  callback? And what is it that we're  passing to** `glutDisplayFunc`?

and, since I **wanted to register a function that had passed arguments, I search a C++ analogy for python lambda functions, and found similar lambda function, but it didn't  work out: **

```
#include <iostream>

void line(int a,  int b){
//some code that does some plotting  in  the  display window
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){

     auto callback = [](void)->void{
             line(a,b);
           };

     glutDisplayFunc(callback);
     glutMainLoop();
}
```

This totally fails,the error that is shown is:

```
no suitable conversion function from "lambda []void ()->void" to "void (*)()" exists
```

This was using my python analogy, but what's the solution to this problem? The major parts of confusion are highlighted in bold.

Comment: In C++ non-member functions naturally decays to pointers to themselves. In this context `line` is equal to `&line`.

Comment: The first half of your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073066/g-calling-a-function-without-parenthesis-not-f-but-f-why-does-it-alwa).  I suggest deleting it from your question and just ask why you can't pass the lambda.

Comment: Lambdas have compiler-generated types that are distinct from all other types - in particular, distinct types from (pointers to) function.   Your function is expecting a pointer to a function that accepts no arguments and return `void` (i.e. `void (*)()`).    No lambda can have that type.

Comment: @Peter But, non capturing lambdas get an implicit conversion operator to a function pointer of their call type.  `[](){}` can be implicitly converted to a `void(*)()`

Comment: Because a pointer to a (non-member) function function can't be converted to `void *`. But it *can* be converted to a `bool`, and the result of that will always be `true` since the pointer is never null.

Comment: @Peter, then what's the solution to what I  want to do then?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  , yeah got that thanks,  Nathan had pointed to me a link to a similar question

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ,  do you know how should I pass a function to`glutDisplayFunc` that has parameters?

Comment: Considering that GLUT will not call the display function with any arguments, you can't. Well you *can* with a little creative casting, but using those arguments will lead to undefined behavior. You can "pass" arguments at compile-time using templates, but there's no way to pass run-time variables.

Comment: @niceboy-programmer: "*do you know how should I pass a function toglutDisplayFunc that has parameters?*" That is a completely different question that has nothing to do with what you asked.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude , how to pass during compile time  using  templates?

Comment: See e.g. [Passing 1 argument (pointer) to glutDisplayFunc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299295/passing-1-argument-pointer-to-glutdisplayfunc)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude,  Yeah, the third answer there mentions that,but, I do not understand the syntax: `glutDisplayFunc(drawScene<(void *)0>)` .

Comment: @niceboy-programmer `nullptr` would have been orders of magnitude better than `(void*)0` there, not to mention much clearer

Answer (score 6):

> It's almost seeming as if we're passing the address of the function, but, clearly from the above program this is not an address

You've got things backwards. It's not `glutDisplayFunc` that's doing the weird magical thing; it's `std::cout`.

Yes, a function name will convert to a function pointer. The combination of `operator<<` overloads for iostreams and C++ overload resolution rules ultimately leads to `<<` treating functions as if they were *boolean values* (yes, really). And thus, your `<< length` is equivalent to doing `<< true`.

If you want the address, you can cast the function pointer to a `void*` before outputting it: `<< reinterpret_cast<void*>(&length)` or the more terse `<< (void*)&length` (though technically this is only conditionally supported by C++, pretty much every real compiler will allow this).

Lastly, in C++, lambdas are not functions; they're *objects*. You cannot pass an object to something that expects a function pointer. You can convert a capture-less lambda into a function pointer, but you can't do that for one which captures values.

Comment: and if you use the `std::boolalpha` manipulator, `std::cout << length` prints `true`

Comment: Could add a quick note about what happens when you cast said pointer to `void*` to bypass/skip/fool/fire the conversion-to-bool